# jQuery Function, Show DIV

Tags: jquery

**Hello Stackers,**

This time not a problem or a Bug, just no knowledge. I've tried to create a Function so that I can Launch a DIV. I want to make it possible that if I run `pushmessage('type','title','content')`, jQuery a div Shows with `.show()`with those Parameters filled in. My Question is, **Is this Possible and does it need PHP? Or is it pure jQuery?** The div should be created, because it hides again. The div is nowhere on the page. Yes it should become visible.

**My DIV**

```
<div class="pushmessage + TYPE +">
        <span class="title">+ TITLE +</span><br/>
        <span class="content">+ CONTENT +</span>
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure what "Launch a DIV" means.  Just making it visible?  Also, is the div already on the page and you are triggering this somewhere else?  This question is too vague to completely answer.

Comment: Edited to make it more clear.

Comment: This is still a bit unclear but I'll code something up that may at least get you on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass your html as one string and add it to DOM on click or some other event

```js
var pushmessage = function(type, title, content) {
  var html = '<div class="pushmessage ' + type + '"><span class="title">' + title + '</span><br/><span class="content">' + content + '</span><div class="loader"></div></div>'
  $(html).hide().appendTo("body").fadeIn("fast");
}

$('button').click(function() {
  pushmessage('lorem', 'Random title', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add div</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. When I Want to let the div appear in another div, Should I change the appendTo? `appendTo(".pushcenter")`

Comment: I could suggest that your `HTML` must specify the `CSS` class like this: `<div class="pushmessage-' + type + '">` or `<div class="pushmessage ' + type + '">` (notice the space after the *pushmessage* word) just to be a bit more "organized".

Comment: Yes you can then use `[class^="pushmessage-"]` attr selector in css, space is even better.

Comment: When I want to add some other code after the insert, like a Time out function for fading it out after a specific time, should I place this after `$(html).hide().appendTo("body").fadeIn("fast");`
  
 `setTimeout(function(){
            $(html).fadeOut("fast",function(){ $(this).remove()});
        }, 5000);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the div is not already on the page you'll need some sort of place holder for where you want it.  You'll have to add styling etc in order to place it where you want it.

```
<div id="placeHolder"></div>
```

In javascript:

```
function pushmessage(type, title, content)
{
    var newDiv = '<div class="pushmessage' + type +'">';
    newDiv+= '<span class="title">' +title + '</span><br/>';
    newDiv+= '<span class="content">' + content + '</span>';
    newDiv+= '<div class="loader"></div>';
    newDiv+= '</div>';
    $('#placeHolder').html(newDiv);
}
```

This probably won't be exactly what you want but it should get you started.

Side note:   This is all javascript.  You won't need PHP here unless you need something back from the server.

Comment: The Placeholder is there: `.pushcenter`

Comment: Then change the last line to $('.pushcenter').html(newDiv)   Also, here is more documentation on jQuery   http://api.jquery.com/html/